# How to install OpenSSL with /crypto/cms/cms_lcl.h and other headers?

Tags: c, installation, openssl

In my program i need to use `CMS_ContentInfo` structure which declared in `openssl/cms.h` but implemented in `/crypto/cms/cms_lcl.c` and this file doesn't exists in openssl include directory.

First i used libssl-dev package (my distro is ubuntu), but when i found there is no more directories in `openssl` directory, i tried to build openssl from sources. Same thing, it still doesn't install files i need. Default installation doesn't includes `/crypto/cms/cms_lcl.c`, `/crypto/cms/cms_lcl.h` and others, and i dont know how to insatll it not copying and pasting.

Comment: Why do you think you need OpenSSL source to write code that uses OpenSSL functions?  Those function implementations are in the *libraries* installed with the base OpenSSL package.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Maybe, but anyway I still need to use CMS_ContentInfo structure and I saw it's implementation in header

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you don't need `cms_lcl.c` per se -- as Andrew Henle commented, likely what you need to compile your program is the headers (e.g. `openssl/cms.h`) and the *libraries* (e.g. `libcrypto.a`).

The only reason you would want `cms_lcl.c` (etc.) specifically is if you want to compile those files into the libraries.

Assuming you just need to compile your code, you'll need to include the header in your code, e.g. `#include <openssl/cms.h>`, and link with the appropriate library, e.g. `g++ ... -lcrypto`.

Here's a recipe I went through to compile a minimal `C` program that uses `CMS_ContentInfo`:

```
root@1bd58893ae55:/# apt-get install -y libssl-dev
```

Here's a minimal code example, adapted from [Using OpenSSL API how can I access a signer's certificate info from a signed file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55654448/5437543), that is probably non-functional (because of my simplification), but is sufficient to show that it compiles:

```
// main.c

#include <openssl/cms.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    BIO *in = NULL;
    CMS_ContentInfo *cms = NULL;
    STACK_OF(CMS_SignerInfo) *ssi = NULL;
    CMS_SignerInfo *si = NULL;
    int ret = 1;

    in = BIO_new_file(argv[1], "r");
    if (!in)
        goto err;

    cms = d2i_CMS_bio(in, NULL);
    if (!cms)
        goto err;

    ssi = CMS_get0_SignerInfos(cms);

    return 0;

err:
    return 1;
}
```

And here's how I compiled and linked:

```
root@1bd58893ae55:/# g++ --version && g++ ./main.c -lcrypto
g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

root@1bd58893ae55:/#
```

The `-lcrypto` means to link the executable with libcrypto, somewhere inside of which is the implementation of `CMS_ContentInfo` that you want to use.

Hope that helps.